# Updating Sharedpreferences values

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i would like to know if it is possible to not update sharedpreferences old files while adding the new ones , I basically have a sport app , one of the fragment where i show live scores of games , now when some matches play first , they get saved but then when there are few other games which dont play at the same time , the first games get updated and get replaced by newer ones , in my case i want to keep them both old and new sharedprefenreces files , thank you .

Comment: I think for this work is more appropriate the Android Database

Comment: You mean i use room db or sqlite db for this purpose , does Sqlite db not update values !!